# WooCommerce: Free Shipping over £500 for Specific Category Only

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, shipping-method

I am trying to write a hook to handle free shipping for orders but I am having a little difficulty getting this to function how I require.

All products over £500 for products within a specific category. (Category A) should be free.

**Example:**

If products in cart from "Category A" => $500 then shipping is FREE (Less than £500 charged normally)

If there are products in cart are from "Category A" and also "Category B" and the value of products from Category A are over £500 then shipping should be FREE for the "Category A" products but the products from "Category B" should be charged as normal.

I have come up with the following hook which appears to be working, but I don't think it's the best way to go about doing this?

I'm far from an expert so any guidance is welcome.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'change_mbe_shipping_price' );
function change_mbe_shipping_price( $rates ) {
    // HERE define your shipping class to find
    $requiredTotal = 0; $totalPrice = []; $shipping_class_ids =[];$tax_rate = 0;
    // Loop through cart items for the current shipping package
    foreach( $pakage['contents'] as $cart_item ) {
        if(in_array(642, $item['data']->get_category_ids())){
            $totalPrice[] = number_format($item['line_subtotal_tax'], 2, '.', '') + number_format($item['line_total'], 2, '.', '');
            $shipping_class_ids[] = $item['data']->get_shipping_class_id();
        }
    }

    // Calculate total order cost for accessories category.
    if(!empty($shipping_class_ids) && !empty($totalPrice)){
        $requiredTotal = array_sum($totalPrice);
    }

    foreach( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ){
        if( $requiredTotal > 500 ){
            // Set cost to zero
            $rates[$rate_key]->cost = 0;

            // Set taxes rate cost to zero
            $taxes = [];
            foreach ($rate->taxes as $key => $tax){
                if( $tax > 0 )
                    $taxes[$key] = 0;
            }
            $rates[$rate_key]->taxes = $taxes;
        }

        //echo "<pre>"; print_r($rates);exit;
    }

    return $rates;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @LoicTheAztec

I feel honoured you replied, your snippets of code have helped me tremendously in the past so thank you very much, you are like Stack Overflow royalty in my opinion.

Comment: Great, so it looks like I'm using the correct hook, just incorrectly.

So to clarify, It is possible to have Free Shipping for products from Category A but also still charge for shipping from Category B in the same Cart?

My hook above kind of works, but it does not take in to account if items in the cart are mixed from Cat A (Free over £500) and also Cat B (Standard Shipping Rules), it just applies a blanket Free Shipping for the whole cart.

I know you're a busy man and I really appreciate any help. I'm really out of my depth here.

Comment: Awesome, thank you :)

Comment: The only way is to split cart into shipping packages based on your categories using `woocommerce_cart_shipping_packages` dedicated hook like on [those related threads](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=woocommerce_cart_shipping_packages), but it's a bit complicated. To check categories in cart items use `has_term()` conditional function like on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65576379/hide-some-shipping-rates-based-on-taxonomy-terms-in-woocommerce-4-8/65579576#65579576)